# Prob. 12, Chap. 4 in Baby Rudin: A uniformly continuous function of a uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

Here is Prob. 12, Chap. 4 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> A uniformly continuous function of a uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous.
>
> State this more precisely and prove it.

Here is my effort:

> Theorem:** Let $\left(X, d_X\right)$,  $\left(Y, d_Y \right)$, and  $\left( Z, d_Z \right)$ be metric spaces, let $f$ be a uniformly continuous mapping of $X$ into $Y$, let $g$ be a uniformly continuous mapping of $f(X)$ into $Z$, and let $h = g \circ f$. Then $h$ is a uniformly continuous mapping of $X$ into $Z$.
>
> Proof:** Let $\varepsilon$ be a given real number such that $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $g$ is a unifromly continuous mapping of $f(X)$ into $Z$, we can find a real number $\eta > 0$ such that
> $$\tag{1} d_Z \left( g \left( y_1 \right), g \left( y_2 \right) \right) < \varepsilon$$ for any points $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $f(X)$ for which $$\tag{2} d_Y \left( y_1, y_2 \right) < \eta.$$
> Now as $f$ is a uniformly continuous mapping of $X$ into $Y$, so, corresponding to the real number $\eta > 0$ in particular, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $$ \tag{3} d_Y \left( f \left(x_1 \right), f \left( x_2 \right)  \right) < \eta$$ for any points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ for which $$ \tag{4} d_X \left( x_1, x_2 \right) < \delta.$$
> So, we can conclude from (1), (2), (3), (4) above that, for any points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ which satisfy $$d_X \left( x_1, x_2 \right) < \delta,$$ the following is true.
> $$ d_Z \left( h \left(x_1 \right), h\left( x_2 \right) \right)  = d_Z \left( g\left( f\left( x_1 \right) \right), g\left( f\left( x_2 \right) \right) \right) < \varepsilon, $$ from which it follows that $h = g \circ f$ is a uniformly continuous mapping of $X$ into $Z$.

Have I managed to get the statement of the theorem right? If so, then is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Looks good to me too. +1.

Comment: Nice! +1 from me as well. Maybe post your proof as an answer!

Comment: @UmbertoP. can you please also have a look at the following question of mine? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120085/prob-11-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-uniform-continuous-extension-from-a-dense-subse

Comment: @positrón0802 thank you. I would be grateful if you could also take time going through my question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120085/prob-11-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-uniform-continuous-extension-from-a-dense-subse.

Comment: @TheCount so nice of you. Can you please also have a look at this post? Here's the link. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120085/prob-11-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-uniform-continuous-extension-from-a-dense-subse

Comment: Don't post a comment like that @SaaqibMahmuud three times in a row to different people; they're all still visible to us.

Comment: @SeanRoberson sorry! I wanted to make sure each one does get to read my request, in case they've moved elsewhere.

Comment: They won't get moved; everybody seems them, and anybody can see any other questions you may have from the main page or your profile.

Comment: It isn't a big deal, Saaqib, don't worry about it. Just don't make a habit of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks perfect. You have the right conceptual idea, as well: simply shrink the ball in $X$ until its image "fits" inside the ball in $Y$, then send it to $Z$. Nicely done.

Comment: can you please also have a look at the question of mine at the following link? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120085/prob-11-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-uniform-continuous-extension-from-a-dense-subse